# Why is the function "funct" not getting executed?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

long funct(string s,long n){
    cout<<"lol";
    long len=s.size();
    long loop = n/len;
    long l = n % len;
    long rem =0;
    long count =0,i;
    for(i=0; i<l;i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == 'a')
        {
            rem++;
        }
    }
    while(i<len)
    {
        if(s[i] == 'a')
        {
            count++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    count += rem;
    long ans = (loop * count) + rem;
    return ans;
}

int main(void) {
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    long ans = funct(s,10);
    cout<<ans<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The flow of program stops at the line which calls the function. It is not executing the function nor does it skip the function call. 
I put a `cout` at the first line of function to debug but even that isn't being executed.

I was trying to find the number of a's by repeating a string up to 10 size.

Thanks for helping. Actually there was an infinite loop inside the function and due to that my first cout wasn't being run due to efficiency reasons.

Comment: Probably some infinite loop.

Comment: Please post the results of your debugging session.  Include the values of variables used at the statement causing the issue.  You may want to draw function calls in the case of recursion.

Comment: Also, you may want to terminate your output text with a newline or `std::endl` to flush the output.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Even the first statement in the function is being executed after the call.

Comment: @DimChtz even the first line of the function is being run after entering the input

Comment: The problem is here: `while ( i < len ) { if ( s[i] == 'a') ....` If the string contains at least one char different than `a` it will get into infinite loop.

Comment: You do realize the program stops waiting for user input on `cin >> s;`. It will stay on this line until you force the buffer to flush (hit `<enter>` or type an awful lot). Then one word will be read into `s`.

Comment: @DimChtz even the first line (cout<<"lol") is being run

Comment: You also need to reset `i` before while, right?

Comment: @MartinYork If I don't call the function and output the input as it is.. It's working fine

Comment: @DimChtz No.. I had to continue with i's old value.. The problem is that even the first line of the function doesn't run

Comment: @SiddharthPandey The first line of the function DOES run. Try to remove both loops and you will see that it does run. It actually gets stuck in the while loop.

Comment: @DimChtz why would the loops have any effect on what's being executed before them?

Comment: Pop a `cout << s[i] << endl;` into both of the loops to see what values are being considered.

Comment: When you debug the code can you step into the function? It might be that you need to declare the function before main and implement it after main.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks.. It's an infinite loop.. And due to efficiency reasons my cout doesn't run before the loops

Comment: Try: `std::cerr << "lol\n";` That will force the output the screen rather than being buffered. Note: The error stream `cerr`.

Comment: I didn't downvote this (-3 is enough :p), but I wanted to explain where those downvotes probably come from. Your question is very specific for just your case; basically you're just asking for help with a programming problem. StackOver flow aims towards questions that benefit others too. I believe there is a site to ask for help with a programming problem too, but I forgot the url.

Answer (score 1):

The function `funct` *is* being called.

The output at the top (`cout<<"lol";`) isn't shown because it isn't being flushed (see Ben Voigt's answer).

The actual problem then is that the function `funct` never returns because it hangs in the `while(i<len)` loop, an infinite loop:

```
while(i<len)

    if(s[i] == 'a')

while(i<len)

    if(s[i] == 'a')
```

And so on and so on. Note that `i` is not changed, so this will repeat for ever.

Comment: Yes.. I mistakenly put the incrementation of i inside the if block. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your loop through the individual alphabets of the string passed to the function, you need

```
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
```

instead of

```
for(i=0;i<l;i++)
```

I ran it and it worked [here](https://repl.it/repls/UncomfortableVeneratedNewsaggregator)
that's line 13 of your code

Comment: Actually I only needed to iterate upto l separately and store a's in rem.. And then iterate the rest and store them in count

Answer (score 0):

You're the victim of output buffering.

By default, `cout` will only actually write outgoing data to the OS when a newline character is encountered.  This is an efficiency thing, if you're building a data file from a thousand different variables, no point in writing to the disk 1000 times.  Instead the whole string gets built up in memory.

You really should be using `cerr` for debug tracing, as it is unbuffered.  But you can make `cout` work too, just remember to write a newline or flush:

```
std::cout << "lol\n"; // this works

std::cout << "lol" << std::flush; // also works
```

Best option:

```
std::cerr << "lol";
```

Comment: @AndréSanson Thanks. I was running an infinite loop into the function hence the first line wasn't being executed before the loops.

Comment: @SiddharthPandey I don't think thats true at all. The infinite loop was your problem but the output was not being displayed because it was buffered like `Ben` described and only output once the buffer was flushed after you fixed the bug and allowed the code to end the program.

Comment: @MartinYork Yes  I meant that the infinite loops didn't let the "lol" print because it got stuck in buffer and waited for either endline or program to end